# New HTML5 canvas method: addHitRegion

Tags: html, canvas

I've been reading a bit about the forthcoming `addHitRegion()` method for `canvas`. From what I've read it sounds much like a way to add clickable hotspots to your canvas - is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never heard of that before, but it seems clickable hotspots are one of the possible uses.

From the current [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#hit-region):

> Hit regions can be used for a variety of purposes:
>
> - With an ID, they can make hit detection easier by having the user agent check which region the mouse is over and include the ID in the mouse events.
> - With a control, they can make routing events to DOM elements automatic, allowing e.g. clicks on a canvas to automatically submit a form via a button element.
> - With a label, they can make it easier for users to explore a canvas without seeing it, e.g. by touch on a mobile device.
> - With a cursor, they can make it easier for different regions of the canvas to have different cursors, with the user agent automatically switching between them.

Comment: @Richard That's really nice! Too bad it's not implemented by browsers yet.