# Hit-regions for gwt canvas?

Tags: java, gwt

I read about [HTML5 hit regions for a canvas](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2012/october/new-html5-canvas-features.html), which describes it for JS: `context.addHitRegion({ id: 'The First Button' });`

Is there anything similar for GWT Canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am not 100% sure if this is part of the official Canvas specs ([New HTML5 canvas method: addHitRegion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115597/new-html5-canvas-method-addhitregion)).

It seems to be a recent addition to the spec and so it's not really clear if it is already supported by any browser ([New HTML5 Canvas API support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378885/new-html5-canvas-api-support)).

The GWT wrapper for Canvas will most likely **NOT** have a function `addHitRegion`. However it is fairly easy to extend the [Canvas](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/canvas/client/Canvas.html) class and add a function `addHitRegion` which makes a JSNI call to the native Javascript function.